# How to code a Nancy bind with a mix of array and non-array post variables

Tags: c#, arrays, http-post, nancy

I'm having problems with Nancy bind using a mixture of array and non-array post variables.

My form looks like this:

```
<form name="input" action="/new/" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br />
Address1: <input type="text" name="Address[0]"><br />
Address2: <input type="text" name="Address[1]"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My model like this:

```
public class UserModel2
  {
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string[] Address { get; set; } 
  }
```

and when I bind with:

```
var f = this.Bind<UserModel2>();
```

then only the `FirstName` and `LastName` get set and `Address` is `null`.
when I change address to `IEnumerable<string>` the same results.

when I bind to a list of `Usermodel2` like this:

```
var f = this.Bind<List<UserModel2>>();
```

then I get a list of two with each having the address variables but then the `FirstName` and `LastName` set to `null`.

What is the correct way of doing this? or is a mix not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested it myself and this how I got this working as expected:

```
<form name="input" action="/new/" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br />
Address1: <input type="text" name="Address"><br />
Address2: <input type="text" name="Address"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is a sample project: 
https://github.com/mdymel/ModelListBinding

Comment: I still get a null result. Can you also post your model and how you bind? Thanks.

Comment: I've pushed it to github and added a link here.

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now. I did forget the `{get; set;}` on the property. This means that the Nancy Wiki is incorrect, it has an example with the fields being indexed in the form. Also I never got a bind to work on fields which should be possible says the wiki.

Comment: Wiki is correct - fields are indexed where they bind to a list of objects (name[0], Commits[0], name[1], Commits[1]) , not a list of strings like in your case.

PS. you can accept the anwer ;)